# Customize Number in Custom Picker so that it's a Multiplier of 5

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, slider

I used a code from [here](https://priva28.medium.com/making-a-custom-slider-in-swiftui-db440cd6d88c), and I want to make it so that the custom slider only represents a number that is a multiplier of 5 in the range 5 to 180. I am using SwiftUI in XCode 12.5, and here is the code. PS. This is not the entire code, but I want the code to be in proximity to this code.

```
CustomSlider(value: $someValue, range: 5...180)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll have a better chance of getting an answer if you show something that you've tried already, because this sounds like you are asking for somebody to write the code for you.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Method 1

The first method is to round the value of `someValue` to the nearest 5 every time it changes. The slider can only go up in fixed increments, so it does look a bit jumpy.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var someValue: CGFloat = 5

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomSlider(value: $someValue, range: 5 ... 180)

            Text("Value: \(someValue)")
        }
        .onChange(of: someValue) { newValue in
            someValue = round(newValue / 5) * 5
        }
    }
}
```

#### Method 2

This method the slider is continuous, but the values you read from `sliderValue` is rounded to the nearest 5. I prefer this method as it feels smoother.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var someValue: CGFloat = 5
    private var sliderValue: CGFloat {
        round(someValue / 5) * 5
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomSlider(value: $someValue, range: 5 ... 180)

            Text("Value: \(sliderValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for. Have a good day!